# Keep returning "Instance of 'Future<dynamic>" instead of String (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I've looked everywhere and found no solution. I'm wanting to return the result count from a query, yet I'm having troubles. Keep getting **"Instance of 'Future" instead of String**

I'm using the Singleton pattern.

- DB method (database.dart):

```
    Future<int> getUnCompletedTaskCount () async {
    final db = await database;
    var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE isComplete = 0");
    int count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(result);
    return count;
  }
```

- My method in main.dart:

```
    getResultCount () async {
    final value = await DBProvider.db.getUnCompletedTaskCount();
    return value;
  }
```

- Calling the method by:

```
    getResultCount().toString()
```

Comment: You are using 'async' on your function so You can use `FutureBuilder` to fetch data from database, api ,...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have an example?

Comment: for FutureBuilder ? on [medium.com](https://medium.com/) You can find tons of them.

Maybe [This one](https://medium.com/@jimmyhott/using-futurebuilder-to-create-a-better-widget-4c7d4f52a329) be helpful.
If you need help to refactor your code, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: I tried that and I think I did it correctly. Now, it's printing the result, but just not displaying it into a Text widget.

getResultCount () async {
    var x;
    var value = await DBProvider.db.getUnCompletedTaskCount().then((val) {
      x = val;
    });
    print(x.toString() + "test");
    return x;
  }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how You're going to use this function, If you need it to get number of completed tasks and then draw something on screen(Like show a list of them or show number of them), I myself use FutureBuilder,Like Below:

```dart
FutureBuilder<int>(
  future: getResultCount(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return Text('Number Of completed : ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return Container();
  },
)
```

So when it completely fetch it, it shows a Text Widget, Otherwise it shows nothing(empty Container)

But if you need it in lets say an equation or something, you can do something like this:

```dart
  await getResultCount().then((val){
      // do some operation
    });
```

But again it totaly depends on your code and need.

When you need result of a future function in your code use `await` before it.

Like `getResultCount()` use `await` when You need to use the result of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now, it's saying "build function returned null". Agh, I'm banging my head with this...

Comment: You should use FutureBuilder as a Widget in somewhere like child,... 
Because it's like normal widgets, if data isn't fetched completely, it returns Container(), otherwise the Text widget.
so if you're using it in Build function, use `return` before FutureBuilder.

Comment: This solved my problem. I left it for a few days, and the solution seemed to have now worked. Thank you!

Comment: thank you. I had a similar instance only that I had not used the await key word

Answer (score 4):

- Error shows that you are trying to use value of `Future<dynamic>` as `String` which it won't let you because value haven't returned yet.
- So basically what we have to do here is wait for value to be returned by using `then` keyword.

Like here.

```
 getResultCount().then((value){

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

> On Net Ninja flutter tutorial : User.signInAnon() returns "Future dynamic" ... you should add await in sign_in.dart

```
  onPressed: () async {
            dynamic result = **await** _auth.signInAnon();

            if (result == null) {
              print('Not signed In');
            } else {
              print('Signed In ');
              print(result);
            }
          },
```